# htaccess with cakephp workds for windows but not for ubuntu

Tags: .htaccess, ubuntu-12.04, cakephp-2.3

I am working on Windows and it had mod_rewrite engine off. so My cakephp project work fine on that but now I have shifted to the UBuntu and it has mod_rewrite engine on. My project ends with Not found error for the css images and other resources. What changes I need to do if my mod_rewrite engine is on and I wanna run project correctly I am using 2.3 version of Cakephp..

project/app/index.php

```
require 'webroot' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'index.php';
```

project/app/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

project/app/webroot/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Errors are

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/project/css/citynightlife/bootstrap.min.css"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/project/css/citynightlife/menu/styles/lwhite.css"
```

This network error is for all css, js and images.

Comment: Where do these css/images/js files actually reside in your document root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking your virtual host file in your etc/apache2/sites-available folder.   You should have the following set to All in your  tags.

```
AllowOverride All
```